# Exit loop when the collection is changed?

Tags: vb.net, loops, pagination, enumeration

I have a For Loop which lists items from a collection (like 5 items per page).
The user can go to other pages by clicking other page buttons, but this causes the following error if the current page is still being listed.

```
Collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute.
```

How would I abort the listing of the current page when the user clicks the other page buttons before the list is finished?

I tried making two boolean variables called "isListing" and "isSkipping", then I tried putting the For Loop in a While statement like this:

```
Public Sub list()
    lines.Items.Clear()
    lines = New List(Of String)()
    Dim reader As StringReader = New StringReader(listLines) 'listLines obtained from a file
    Do Until reader.Peek = -1
        lines.Add(reader.ReadLine)
    Loop
    isListing = True

    While Not isSkipping AndAlso isListing
        For Each line As String In lines
            'List Page
        Next
        isListing = False
    End While
End Sub
```

And the page button like:

```
Private Sub btnPage_Click(...) ...
    If isListing Then isSkipping = True Else isSkipping = False
    list()
End Sub
```

But this causes the same error.

Any help appreciated~!

Comment: Do you change `lines` in the `For Each`(Add,Remove,Modify)? That's not allowed. Is this a multihreading application (f.e. as ASP.NET)? Is lines shared?

Comment: `lines` isn't changed within the loop, but it's changed from outside, it's cleared when list() is called then the new items are added. I'll update my previous post to reflect this.

It is multi-threaded, I use a threading class to invoke UI changes.. it's a lot of code which I didn't think to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abort the listing in progress you would need to put a command to abort the listing inside the foreach loop. You can also change the foreach loop to a for loop, which would remove that exception but could have other consequences like a null reference exception. It also makes sense to move the wait inside the button click event where you can easily see what's going to happen when the button is clicked.

There is probably a more robust way to handle this, but it's hard to say without seeing more code.

```
Private Sub btnPage_Click(...) ...
    While(isListing) 
        isSkipping = true 
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While
    isSkipping = false 
    list()
End Sub

Public Sub list()
    isListing = true
    For Each line As String In lines
        'List Page
        If isSkipping then 
            isListing = false
            return
        End If
    Next
    isListing = false
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution only works every second time the button is pressed.
The button causes an increment of the index, so every 2nd page will be skipped if the current page is aborted.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't reset isSkipping after exiting the loop. See the updated code above.

Comment: Seems random to whether it works or not.. some times it'll just prevent the listing from continuing.

I've instead implemented your solution as a sort of stop toggle (user has to click the button once to abort the current listing, then again to do the next listing).

Regardless, thank you.

Comment: I'm sure it could be made more reliable, but it's difficult without the code that creates the list. I keep thinking about it and update if I come up with something.